# ionic Package io.ionic.starter signatures error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

My ionic project working nicely in command: ionic lab but when I execute "ionic cordova run" in terminal for build this app in android I am having the following error.
    Error: Failed to install apk to device: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package io.ionic.starter signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Delete all the previous ionic apps from your android phone. Then run the command

```
ionic run android
```

or

```
ionic run android --device
```

Hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score 8):

When you previously installed any app with default package name given by ionic and trying to install another app with the same default package name, it will throw this error.

In **config.xml** file, change package name(id attribute of widget tag) from io.ionic.starter to any other package name of your choice(ex: com.example.hello)

This way you can keep all your ionic apps installed.

Answer (score 1):

On android device, go to `Settings > Apps` and find your app in listing and open `App info`.

Click on the `More Icon` and select `Uninstall for all users`.

[image]

Then run commond `ionic cordova run android`.

Comment: sorry there is no app in my phone name "ionic view"

Comment: @rafatahmed, it was just for demo. i was asking to do with your app.

Comment: i said find your app in listing.

Comment: This is correct. If you install an app on android, then "uninstall" in the first 24 hours, it doesnt actually uninstall. It sits in a queue.  You have to go to Settings -> General -> Apps as mentioned above, and click the app and then uninstall